# python-daemon does not work if called by function

Tags: python, daemon, function-calls, python-daemon

I'm trying to use the python-daemon library to spawn a daemon that will write to a file.

When I create the daemon directly in the "if __name__ == '__main__'" statement, the daemon successfully writes to the file:

```
from daemon import DaemonContext
def main():
    my_file.write("Daemon creation was successful")
    my_file.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_file = open("my_file", "w+")
    with DaemonContext(files_preserve=[my_file.fileno()]):
        main()
```

However, when I use a separate function for daemon creation, the daemon does **not** write to the file:

```
from daemon import DaemonContext
def main():
    my_file.write("Daemon creation was successful")
    my_file.close()

def create_daemon():
    my_file = open("my_file", "w+")
    with DaemonContext(files_preserve=[my_file.fileno()]):
        main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_daemon()
```

The if statement in the working example and the "create_daemon" function in the non-working example share the exact same code. Why then, am I unable to create a daemon by calling a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with daemons. `main` doesn't have access to `my_file`; you didn't pass the file in as an argument or anything.

Comment: Can you please explain further? Since the first example works, shouldn't the second one work as well? How does the if statement (from the working example)  give main acess to the file while "create_daemon" does not?

Comment: @Cat: Look up local and global variables.

Comment: Ah, I see. In the first example, my_file creates a global variable which main automatically has access to. In the second example, my_file is a local variable which main has no access to. I'm not sure how I missed that, but thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, the `main` function references `my_file` which is not in that function's scope.

```python
def main():
    my_file.write("Daemon creation was successful")
    my_file.close()
```

That function will (if your example is complete) raise a `NameError` for the `my_file` name.

One way to correct that is to make `my_file` a parameter of `main`.